# Use JavaScript to determine file type when uploading a file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm just getting into JavaScript, so I apologize if my code is not the cleanest.

I'm trying to figure out how to get Javascript to recognize the file extension so it can act on it appropriately. Given the code below, **my script is allowing PDF, docx, and doc files, but it is rejecting pages documents**. I'm unsure why though.

```
var ext = $('#resume').val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase();

// Reject file if it is not one of the specified filetypes
if ($.inArray(ext, ['pdf','pages','docx','doc']) == -1) {
    error.innerHTML = "<span class=\"red\">The file you selected does not meet document type requirements.<br>We can only accept pdf, pages, docx, and doc documents.</span>";
    return false;
}
```

Comment: The file extension of Pages is maybe different. It may not be a file at all (but a bundle/directory). And it has recently rather radically changed, so it might depend on the Pages version. Apple stuff is a bit tricky.

Comment: What is the full filename for a pages document? What if the filename contains more than one '.'? Instead of pop()ing the first item off the array, how about the last index of the array after the split, just in case?

Comment: can you describe what kind of  "pages documents"

Comment: why don't you log the file extension of the .pages file  on the console and see what it gives ya?

Comment: I appreciate your comments! I'm gonna try what you're saying. Basically the pages documents are the ones from Apple's Pages app. For those of you who are unsure what that is. I just wanna be able to accept the documents from multiple platforms rather than just pdfs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out why it wasn't accepting pages documents, because they are disguised as zip documents. Also, I modified my code to better catch the extensions. Here is what I used

```
var fileName = document.getElementById("resume").value;
var ext = fileName.substr((fileName.lastIndexOf('.') + 1));

if (ext != "pdf" && ext != "pages" && ext != "docx" && ext != "doc" && ext != "zip") { // Reject file if it is not one of the specified filetypes
return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var fileName = $('#resume').val();
var ext = fileName.substr(fileName.lastIndexOf("."), fileName.length);
```